# How do I iterate through this sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Relative newbie to python and even newer to sqlalchemy. I have the following:

Without a subquery, when I join 2 tables without a subquery each row returned is essentially 2 objects:

```
query = DBSession.query(Table1,Table2).outerjoin(Table2,Table1.id==Table2.id)
   for row in query:
       # returns (<myproject.models.Table1 object at 0x3ad2e50>,<myproject.models.Table2 object at 0x3ad2e50>)
```

With a subquery, the behavior changes:

```
subquery = DBSession.query(Table1).order_by(Table1.d.desc()).subquery() 
query = DBSession.query(subquery,Table2).outerjoin(Table2,subquery.c.id==Table2.id).group_by(subquery.c.id) 



for row in query:
    # hoping for 2 objects (<myproject.models.Table1 object at 0x3ad2e50>,<myproject.models.Table2 object at 0x3ad2e50>)
    # receiving (1,'Dave Thomas',10001,<myproject.models.Table1 object at 0x3ad2e50>)
```

How can I get 2 objects for my subquery above? The columns of Table1 may change someday and thus I don't know what position  will be at in the tuple.

thanks!

Comment: Your results are a little confusing. Normally, a subquery must return a scalar result (i.e. one single value) if it is in a `SELECT` context (which you achieve in SQLAlchemy by issuing `as_scalar`). To now trace your problem turn on logging (on `create_engine` pass in `echo=True` or even `echo="debug"`). This will give you the executed SQL statements. You can then see (and execute) them yourself and see if this is really a SQLAlchemy problem or if you need to fix your query first.

Comment: The query runs fine. I just want it to return two objects per row. Please re-read

Comment: I got that. Please try to turn on logging and look at the executed queries. Compare those with the queries you actually want to execute and check if you can fix that. If you get stuck (either writing it in plain SQL or converting it to SQLAlchemy queries) update your question with the details and I will help you trace the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an alias for the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the trick?

```
subsubquery = DBSession.query(Table1).order_by(Table1.d.desc()).subquery() 
subquery = DBSession.query(subsubquery,Table2).outerjoin(Table2,subsubquery.c.id==Table2.id).group_by(subsubquery.c.id).subquery( with_labels = True )
query = DBSession.query(Table1,Table2).select_from( subquery )
```